# Why is AdvancedDataGrid not updating when the HierarchicalData dataProvider is updated?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, hierarchical-data, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid (ADG) with a HierarchicalData dataProvider:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    dataProvider="{__model.myHierarchicalData}" 
    displayItemsExpanded="true" sortExpertMode="true" dropEnabled="true" 
    sortableColumns="false" draggableColumns="false" 
    resizableColumns="true" textAlign="left" defaultLeafIcon="{null}" 
    folderOpenIcon="{null}" folderClosedIcon="{null}"/>
```

When I initially set the HierarchicalData instance in the Model, it is displayed as expected:

```
function buildHierarchicalData(parentItems:ArrayCollection):void
{
    __model.myHierarchicalData = new HierarchicalData();

    __model.myHierarchicalData.source = parentItems;
}
```

**parentItems** is a Collection of ParentItem valueObjects:

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public class ParentItem
    {
        public var children:ArrayCollection;

        public var label:String;
    }
}
```

However, when I move child items from one parent to another (via drag-and-drop), the update is not visible, using this code:

```
function moveChildren(movedChildren:Array /* of ParentItem */):void
{
    parentItem.children = new ArrayCollection(movedChildren);
}
```

For some reason, however, this DOES work:

```
function moveChildren(movedChildren:Array /* of ParentItem */):void
{
    parentItem.children.source = movedChildren;
}
```

Why do I have to update the source of the ArrayCollection???

Comment: Try making children Bindable.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is bindable in my code (see fixed post above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to dirkgently for directing me to the answer. I am now eliminating the need for a HierarchicalData property in my model, and instead setting the Hierarchical dataProvider right in the MXML:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:HierarchicalData source="{__model.parentItems}" />
    </mx:dataProvider>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_07.html). It is recommended to use a bindable `ArrayCollection` always when dealing with `dataProviders`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found my answer there.

Comment: Actually, this made my code nicer, but didn't fix my problem. The class is bindable, but the dataprovider is still not updating correctly unless i update the source of the item.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
IHierarchicalCollectionView(__model.myHierarchicalData).refresh();
```